# Questions regarding horizontal scrolling in Microsoft's Win32 text scrolling example

Tags: c++, winapi, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

Microsoft has an example code for vertical and horizontal text scrolling. It can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-text-in-scroll-bars). I understand the vertical scrolling part but I have some questions regarding the horizontal scrolling part.

1. The example defines a variable called `xClientMax`. On `WM_CREATE` message, it is set to the maximum width of the area that can be horizontally scrolled. (The comment of the code says its a "maximum width for client area" but I think my description is more accurate) Then `xClientMax / xChar` becomes the maximum width of the area that can be horizontally scrolled in `xChar` units. (`xChar` is set to `tm.tmAveCharWidth` from `GetTextMetrics`) Now I would expect the range of the horizontal scroll bar to be set like:

   ```
    si.nMin   = 0;
    si.nMax   = xClientMax / xChar - 1;
    si.nPage  = xClient / xChar; 
    SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);
   ```

   But instead it is set like:

   ```
   si.nMin   = 0;
   si.nMax   = 2 + xClientMax / xChar;
   si.nPage  = xClient / xChar; 
   SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);
   ```

   Why is this?
2. The example performs a synchronous update by calling `UpdateWindow` after `ScrollWindow` for vertical scroll bar but not for horizontal scroll bar. Why?

Comment: Just guessing, but 1) possibly because text is easier to read if it's not hard up against a vertical border - alternatively, maybe to leave room on the right of the text for the caret?  and 2) possibly because a horiz scroll is more expensive to perform (more lines need to be redrawn) - alternatively, they forgot

Comment: @Jonathan Potter
As for my second question indeed that seems to be the reason; any change to the horizontal scroll position will result in all the lines to be redrawn while this won't necessarily happen when vertical scroll position changes. As for my first question in `WM_PAINT` the program does indeed use `x = xChar * (1 - xPos);` instead of `x = xChar * (- Pos);` which causes the text to have a distance from left border. There is a difference of 3 between `xClientMax / xChar - 1` and `2 + xClientMax / xChar;` though. The other two are perhaps for the right border and the caret as you said.